# Slim templates and TailwindCSS use ' : ' in class declaration

Tags: slim-lang, tailwind-css

TailwindCSS is looking like a great frontend tool but I'm wondering how to use it with the Rails Slim template language?

For example:

```
<div class="bg-red-500 sm:bg-green-500 md:bg-blue-500 lg:bg-pink-500 xl:bg-teal-500"></div>
```

If I run it through HTML2SLIM I get this recommendation:

```
.bg-red-500.sm:bg-green-500.md:bg-blue-500.lg:bg-pink-500.xl:bg-teal-500
```

Which produces the following HTML:

```
<div class="bg-red-500 sm">
   <bg-green-500 class="md">
      <bg-blue-500 class="lg">
         <bg-pink-500 class="xl">
            <bg-teal-500></bg-teal-500>
         </bg-pink-500>
      </bg-blue-500>
   </bg-green-500>
</div>
```

It seems that the colon ':' is interperted as multiple html elemments. Im wondering if there's a way around this?  I'd love to use Slim with TailwindCSS.

So far I've made some progress using Rails' content_tag:

```
= content_tag :span, 'Accounts', class: 'invisible md:visible lg:visible'
```

But I can only go so far with this.

Comment: (slim now supports ":" in class names)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to configure Tailwind to use another separator as documented here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration/#separator

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  separator: "_",
}
```

Then you could do `.sm_bg-green-500` and so on.

There are also class names like `.w-1/2` in Tailwind, that are not affected by this setting. You could [add custom class names](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width/#customizing) to work around that, e.g.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  …
  theme: {
    extend: {
      width: {
        "1-of-2": "50%"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then use `.w-1-of-2`.

Comment: Note that Slim 4.1.0 improved Tailwind support without having to do some of these things: https://github.com/slim-template/slim/pull/841

Answer (score 2):

It's just not possible to have these colons in the class shorthand notation. You can do the following though

```
div class="bg-red-500.sm::bg-green-500.md:bg-blue-500.lg:bg-pink-500.xl:bg-teal-500"
```

which results in the desired HTML:

```
<div class="bg-red-500 sm:bg-green-500 md:bg-blue-500 lg:bg-pink-500 xl:bg-teal-500"></div>
```

Comment: It sucks to have to add div with the class attribute, but This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution `module.exports = { separator: "_" }` as someone suggests is bad:

1. `.sm_bg-green-500` looks worse than `.sm:bg-green-500`
2. You will have issues with class names like `my-block__my-element`. (For some tasks tailwind is not enough and I use BEM naming in such cases)

Instead – use named classes, eg.:

```css
/*app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css*/
.magic-btn {
  @apply bg-red-500 sm:bg-green-500;
}
```

in template:

```
btn.magic-btn
```

Answer (score 0):

The colon stuff was fixed in 2020 but had problem with decimal widths/sizes

```
..text-sm.px-4.py-2.5..
```

if you have to use decimal width, add it to a class attribute:

```
button.text-sm.px-4.text-center.inline-flex[class="py-2.5"]
```